# Leer varias palabras de la entrada estándar con java.util.Scanner

Tags: java

```
package agenda.test;
import agenda.dao.ContactoDAO;
import agenda.entidades.Contacto;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class AgendaTelefonica {

public static void main(String[] args){
    Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
    boolean system= true;

    while(system){
        System.out.println("  --------------------------  ");
        System.out.println("    Agenda Telef\u00f3nica    ");
        System.out.println("  --------------------------  ");
        System.out.println("");

        System.out.println("  --------------------");
        System.out.println("        MEN\u00da     ");
        System.out.println("  --------------------");

        System.out.println("\n1-Ingresar un contacto \n2-Mostrar contactos");

        agenda.dao.ContactoDAO contactoDao=new agenda.dao.ContactoDAO();


        int select;

        select = scan.nextInt();
        switch(select){
            case 1:  
                System.out.println("    Ingrese un contacto:");
                Contacto contacto=new Contacto();

                System.out.print("Nombre        ::");
                contacto.setNombre(scan.next());

                System.out.print("Tel\u00e9fono ::");
                contacto.setTelefono(scan.next());

                System.out.print("Edad          ::");
                contacto.setEdad(scan.nextInt());

                contactoDao.crearContacto(contacto);
        break;
            case 2:
                System.out.println("  -----------------  ");
                System.out.println("      CONTACTOS      ");
                System.out.println("  -----------------  \n");


                contactoDao.mostrarContactos();
                ArrayList<Contacto> contactos=contactoDao.mostrarContactos();
        for (Contacto contactox : contactos) {
            System.out.println("Nombre:: "+contactox.getNombre());
            System.out.println("Tel\u00e9fono:: "+contactox.getTelefono());
            System.out.println("Edad:: "+contactox.getEdad());
            System.out.println("----------------------------");
        }

        break;
            case 0:
            system=false;

        break;
        }
    }
}
}
```

En ContactoDAO sólo tengo los métodos de el POJO o entidad Contacto, el cual sólo tiene métodos *get y set*:

```
package agenda.dao;
import agenda.entidades.Contacto;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ContactoDAO {

private ArrayList<Contacto> contactos=new ArrayList<>();

public void crearContacto(Contacto contacto){
contactos.add(contacto);

}
public ArrayList<Contacto> mostrarContactos(){
    return contactos;
}
```

}

1) Cuando lo corro en NetBeans me deja llenar el formulario de crear un contacto. Pero sólo una palabra, porque si no, salta a esto:

```
  1-Ingresar un contacto 
  2-Mostrar contactos
  1
Ingrese un contacto:
Nombre        ::Juan Perez
Teléfono ::Edad          ::
```

Y no me permite ingresar el teléfono

2)Al darle a la opción dos, no me presenta nada, sólo regresa a mostrarme el Menú

Hasta ahora sólo esos dos problemitas tengo. Agradezco sus observaciones de verdad

Comment: La idea es que cada pregunta se refiera a un problema concreto. En principio no se debe crear una pregunta para varios problemas distintos. Tampoco se debe ir editando la pregunta para añadir más problemas que te vayas encontrando. También he editado el título para que sea más descriptivo, simplemente decir "tengo un problema" no sirve de mucho como título.

Comment: El problema de la opción 2 es que tienes la creación de `contactoDao` dentro del bucle while, por lo que lo sobreescribes cada vez que muestras el menú. Saca la creación del DAO antes del bucle y te funcionará.

Comment: Gracias @Pablo, tomaré en cuenta tu sugerencia

Answer (score 0):

Recordemos que la clase Scanner al final es un buffer; la razón de cuando ingresas el nombre del contacto, en este caso fue **Juan Perez** el token Juan se guarda en el miembro `nombre` de tu clase `Contacto` gracias al `scan.next();`, mientras que Perez es el siguiente token en el buffer y automáticamente el scanner manda ese valor al siguiente `next()`. Es la razón del por qué se salta el ingresar el teléfono, ya que el `scan.next();` toma el valor que queda en el buffer, en este caso `Perez`.

Una solución poco elegante, pero eficaz es usar el método `.nextLine();` para que consuma toda la cadena de caracteres y sea tratado como un solo token.

El código quedaría algo así:

```
case 1:
                System.out.println("    Ingrese un contacto:");
                Contacto contacto=new Contacto();

                System.out.print("Nombre        ::");
                sc.nextLine();
                contacto.setNombre(sc.nextLine());

                System.out.print("Telefono ::");
                contacto.setTelefono(sc.nextLine());

                System.out.print("Edad          ::");
                contacto.setEdad(Integer.parseInt(sc.nextLine()));

                contactoDAO.crearContacto(contacto);
                break;
case 2:
                //El resto de tu lógica...
```

La razón de usar el método `.nextLine();` antes del setter del nombre del contacto es básicamente para consumir la linea anterior a ella y así el `Scanner` no la tome como el siguiente token y cause el efecto de que 'se esta saltando esa entrada', ya que en realidad no se la esta saltando.

Te recomendaría que uses `BufferedReader` para la lectura y para el parsing de los tokens uses el `Scanner`.

**NOTA**: Como te dijeron en los comentarios, necesitas sacar tu sentencia `agenda.dao.ContactoDAO contactoDao=new agenda.dao.ContactoDAO();` del ciclo `while` ya que si no haces esto, la referencia de esa variable se estaría sobreescribiendo siempre, causando que los contactos que sean guardados se pierdan.

Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda @Jesús/ Me funciona mucho mejor con el BufferedReader. Había hecho lo de (sc.nextLine()) pero igual tenía problemas

Comment: RE: necesitas sacar tu sentencia `agenda.dao.ContactoDAO contactoDao=new agenda.dao.ContactoDAO();` del ciclo `while` ya que si no haces esto, la referencia de esa variable se estaría sobreescribiendo siempre, causando que los contactos que sean guardados se pierdan.

Esta sería la razón por la cual el `case 2` del `switch` no se me ejecuta (Mostrar contactos)? Saludos

Comment: Exactamente, te recomendaría sacar esa sentencia fuera del ciclo while y listo. Ya no tendrías problemas para el mostrado de los usuarios. Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias de verdad mi hermano. Ahora, ¿por qué pasa esto al declarar el objeto dentro del ciclo?

Comment: Esto se debe a la sentencia `new` que usas para inicializar el objeto `agenda.dao.ContactoDAO contactoDao=new agenda.dao.ContactoDAO();`. ¿Por qué se debe esto? Básicamente es que cada vez que usas la palabra reservada `new`, estas creando una nueva instancia de un objeto, en este caso es el objeto `ContactoDAO` y si te fijas, cada vez que pasa una interación en el ciclo, se repite el segmento de código `agenda.dao.ContactoDAO contactoDao=new agenda.dao.ContactoDAO();`. Causando que se vuelva a crear un nuevo objeto sobre la referencia `contactoDao`.

Comment: Vaya, ya comprendo @JesúsA.MezaG.. Muchas gracias por tu ayuda

Answer (score -2):

pues este tipo de errores es muy común cuando se utiliza un Scanner .. te podría recomendar que utilices mejor  `BufferedInputStream`.
Pero si insistes en utilizar el Scanner puedes probar cambiando el

```
(scan.nextInt());
```

por

```
(scan.nextLine());
```

o por

```
(scan.nextByte());
```

Espero te funcione.

Comment: Sí, he usado lo de la clase predefinida  _BufferedInputStream_ y me corre bien. El único problema que tengo es que no me corre el case 2: sólo me imprime el título: --------CONTACTOS---------